# develop windows phone 7 using XNA saving the game

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

how is it possible to save information?

for example.
i have a game that if it beats the highest score. it replaces the highest score. 
and everytime the application/game is ran. it displays the latest highest score?

how is it possible to save game info?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something called `IsolatedStorage`. This is an app specific datastore that persists between app instances.

Read all about it here: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/basics/isolated_storage